# Finding probability density function using CDF method

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm working on the following problem, but I'm not really sure how to approach it - it's different from anything I've seen before!
The problem is as follows: 
Consider the probability density function

> $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \left\{\frac{8+xy^3}{64}\right\}$ if $-1<x<1, -2<y<2$,
>   with probabilility $0$ otherwise.

What I'm trying to do is **find the PDF of $W=2X+Y$,** which is causing me some trouble - in fact I hardly know where to start! So I know the support of X is $-1<x<1$ and the support of Y is $-2<y<2$, since the region is a square. I think this means that the support of W is $-3<w<3$, since $W=2X+Y$.

This is where I start to get confused. I believe in order to find the PDF, I first want to find the CDF of W, and then take the derivative of that. In order to find the CDF, I want to  evaluate a double integral in terms of X and Y with the given PDF. However, I don't know what to set the bounds of these integrals to! In fact, I'm not really sure how to even begin; I feel like it might involve solving for X and Y in terms of W $(y=2x-w)$ and $(x=\frac{y-w}{2})$ but I don't know exactly what (if anything) to do with these!

Thank you so much for your help - I really appreciate it!

Sarah

Comment: Why go from the PDF of (X,Y) to the PDF of W through the CDF of W (with its morass of cases) instead of proceeding directly from PDF to PDF? Are you *asked* to proceed thus?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not yet familiar with the techniques used to go from one pdf to another (so I suppose I am, in a sense, asked to proceed this way).

Comment: These are illogical and unfortunate pedagogical choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin by drawing a sketch of the $x$-$y$ plane and marking on it the region where $f_{X,Y}$ is nonzero. (Hint: it is *not* a square).

STOP. Do not proceed if you have ignored the previous statement and
have not made a sketch. Reading beyond this point is useless.

You are not correct when you say that $W \in (-3,3)$. $W$ can take on values in
$(-4,4)$ since $2\times 1 + 2 = 4$, , So you know already that $F_W(w)=0$ for $w-<4$ and $1$ for $W\geq 4$. Now, pick a *fixed* number $w \in(-4,4)$, and draw the line $2x+y=w$. Then, $W=2X+Y\leq w$ if the point $(X,Y)$ lies on or below this line. Can you integrate to find $P(W\leq w)=F_W(w)$ for *your* chosen value of $w$? (Hint: you may need to break up the integral into two or more parts to carry out the calculation). Lather, rinse, repeat for different choices of $w$ which will give you different lines and different
integrals to compute. You may be able to see a trend developing and ultimately
be able to write a complete expression for $F_W(w)$ like
$$F_W(w) = \begin{cases}0, & w < -4,\\
\cdots,& -4 < w < ?,\\
\cdots,& ? < w <??\\
\cdots & \cdots\\
1, & w \geq 4,\end{cases}$$
after just a few tries with different values of $w$.

Then, differentiate to find the pdf $f_W(w)$ and you are done.

Comment: Thank so much! I just started reading your comment and am in the process of drawing the sketch - from what I can tell $f_{x,y}$ takes on a zero value only when x=1 and y=-2 and x=-1 and y=2; am I missing something else here?

Comment: @SarahJ $f(x,y)=0$ if $|x|\geq 1$ **or** $|y|\geq 2$. That's the meaning of "with probability $0$ otherwise" (Does your homework really say it the way you state it, or did you try to put your own interpretation on what the problem actually says?)

Comment: My apologies, I think I was unclear in my question - I was simply looking at the region bounded by -1<x<1 and -2<y<2; am I wrong in believing it comes out to be a rectangle with width 2 and height 4? (I believe we can ignore the two points on the upper right and lower left edges where $f_[x,y]$=0?

Comment: $f(x,y)$ is nonzero on the _interior_ of the rectangle you describe, and so you can ignore all the sides, not just the corner points. But keep in mind that a single point or even a curve will contribute $0$ to the value of the integrals that you have to compute, and you will get the same answers whether you include or exclude the sides of the rectangles in your integrals.

Comment: Sorry for continuing to bother you, I (hopefully!) just have one more question! I've drawn the sketch and highlighted the non-zero points, and now I'm working on drawing the lines for various W; it looks like the line w=0 (so 0=2x+y) is where the 'split' in the CDF you mentioned above will occur; does it make sense to do something like $\int_{-2}^2\int_{-1}^{y/2}[givenPDF]dxdy$ for the area below that line (-4<w<0) and $\int_{-2}^2\int_{y/2}^{1}[givenPDF]dxdy$ for the area above (0<w<4)? Thanks again!

Comment: @SarahJ You have the right idea that it makes sense to compute $P\{W\leq w\}=F_W(w)$ for $w\in(-4,0)$ and $P\{W>w\}=1-F_W(w)$ for $w\in(0,4)$ by integrating over triangular regions, but your integral limits are incorrect. For $w\in(-4,0)$, the triangle you are integrating over has vertices $(-1,-2), (1+w/2,-2)$ and $(-1,w+2)$ and so you have $$F_W(w) = P\{W \leq w\}=\int_{y=-2}^{w+2}\int_{x=-1}^{(w-y)/2}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy.$$

Comment: Thanks! Fully understand it now; I really appreciate your help!